# Promise.all() stops working before finishing

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I've a very simple script that gets me some info by mapping over an array of around 150 records and the code seems to work fine with smaller number of records but everytime I run it with this 150 records it just stops working and doesn't continue and I think it might be a Promise.all problem.

any idea?

code:

```
const request = require('request');
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const fs = require('fs').promises;

let champions = [];

const getChampData = async hrefs => {
  const requests = hrefs.map(async ({ href }) => {
    try {
      const html = await axios.get(href);
      const $ = cheerio.load(html.data);

      const champName = $('.style__Title-sc-14gxj1e-3 span').text();

      let skins = [];

      $('.style__CarouselItemText-sc-1tlyqoa-16').each((_, el) => {
        const skinName = $(el).text();
        skins.push(skinName);
      });

      const champion = {
        champName,
        skins
      };
      console.log(champion);

      return champion;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  });

  const results = await Promise.all(requests);

  await fs.writeFile('json/champions-skins.json', JSON.stringify(results));
  return results;
};
```

edit #1:

I used a package called p-map with it and now everything works just fine!

```
const axios = require('axios');
const pMap = require('p-map');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const fs = require('fs').promises;

const getChampData = async hrefs => {
  // const champions = JSON.parse(await fs.readFile('json/champions.json'));

  try {
    let champsList = await pMap(hrefs, async ({ href }) => {
      const { data } = await axios(href);

      const $ = cheerio.load(data);

      const champName = $('.style__Title-sc-14gxj1e-3 span').text();

      let skins = [];

      $('.style__CarouselItemText-sc-1tlyqoa-16').each((_, el) => {
        const skinName = $(el).text();
        skins.push(skinName);
      });

      const champion = {
        champName,
        skins
      };

      console.log(champion);

      return champion;
    });
    await fs.writeFile(
      'champions-with-skins-list.json',
      JSON.stringify(champsList)
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
};
```

Comment: Do you get any errors, Any messages? What do you mean when you say mean "it stops"?

Comment: not really, the output is just all from the console.log in the file then it stops after around like 10 - 20 seconds before finishing. i don't think its a code  error because I tried it with less records and it worked just fine, I think maybe promise have a limition or something?

Comment: No, promises don't have a limit. But perhaps network requests do.

Comment: Hmm that could be it actually, do you think there's a way around this?

Comment: Promise.all will stop as soon as any Promise in the array rejects, and you don't have your await wrapped in try/catch, so the error falls on the floor.

Comment: @JaredSmith I just wrapped it and I got an error saying: 'socket hang up'. do you mind explaining what that means?

Comment: @A.Atiyah it means one of your requests failed. Hmm, you wrapping your requests in try/catch *should* stop that from happening...weird.

Comment: @JaredSmith here's something intresting, i played with the code a bit and used a package called pmap and now it worked perfectly fine, i still don't know what the problem was with the normal code but i'll edit it with the working code now

Comment: on error you are not returning, seems issue with some url to get data..

Comment: alright i actually figured what the problem was and for some odd reason its actually *axios*, I don't know why but every single other HTTP client I tried worked just fine but axioms. that's weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Error return is missing. Look like issue with some url to fetch.

```
const getChampData = async hrefs => {
  const requests = hrefs.map(async ({ href }) => {
    try {
      const html = await axios.get(href);
      // rest of the code 
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return []
    }
  });

  const results = await Promise.all(requests);

  await fs.writeFile("json/champions-skins.json", JSON.stringify(results));
  return results;
};
```